# How can I find out the current price of an app on Google Play after I've purchased it?

Tags: google-play-store

After you buy an app, it'll just say "Installed" where the price tag usually is.  I'd like to look up the current price to ensure a sale is still going on as I pass it to others.

Answer (score 4):

Load the application's play store URL in a web browser with incognito/private mode. This way the play store will not be aware that the viewer has already installed the application.